# Repairing Python recursion causes wrong results

Tags: python

I thought I had no problems with my code, but when I started changing values, I eventually ended up with a recursion problem.  I thought I repaired it, but when I looked at the results, they were all wrong.  The results are good when I keep the recursion though.

I used a while loop to try and fix the recursion problem, where instead of calling the spread method recursively, I return the value I would pass to it to the propagate method, and return False if it wouldn't pass a value.  So, as long as the method keeps returning values, it should just rerun the spread method with the result of the previous run.

This code works until it breaks recursion limit:

```
    def spread(self, position):
        for direction in self._directions:
            (x, y) = self.changePosition(position, direction)
            if self.canInfectMatrix[x][y] and not self.contactMatrix[x][y]:
                self.contactMatrix[x][y] = True
                self.spread([x,y])
#                 return [x,y]
#             return False

    def propagate(self):
        # initialize canInfectMatrix and contactMatrix
        self.contactMatrix = [[False for row in range(self.cardinalWidth)] for col in range(self.cardinalWidth)]
        self.canInfectMatrix = [[False for row in range(self.cardinalWidth)] for col in range(self.cardinalWidth)]
        for col in range(self.cardinalWidth):
            for row in range(self.cardinalWidth):
                self.canInfectMatrix[row][col] = self.getsInfected(self._matrix[col][row])
        # Spread infection.
        for x in range(self.cardinalWidth):
            for y in range(self.cardinalWidth):
                if self._matrix[x][y] == "infected":
                    self.spread([x,y])
#                     position = [x,y]
#                     while position:
#                         position = self.spread(position)
```

The following code doesn't work, but I get no errors:

```
    def spread(self, position):
        for direction in self._directions:
            (x, y) = self.changePosition(position, direction)
            if self.canInfectMatrix[x][y] and not self.contactMatrix[x][y]:
                self.contactMatrix[x][y] = True
#                self.spread([x,y])
                 return [x,y]
             return False

    def propagate(self):
        # initialize canInfectMatrix and contactMatrix
        self.contactMatrix = [[False for row in range(self.cardinalWidth)] for col in range(self.cardinalWidth)]
        self.canInfectMatrix = [[False for row in range(self.cardinalWidth)] for col in range(self.cardinalWidth)]
        for col in range(self.cardinalWidth):
            for row in range(self.cardinalWidth):
                self.canInfectMatrix[row][col] = self.getsInfected(self._matrix[col][row])
        # Spread infection.
        for x in range(self.cardinalWidth):
            for y in range(self.cardinalWidth):
                if self._matrix[x][y] == "infected":
#                    self.spread([x,y])
                     position = [x,y]
                     while position:
                         position = self.spread(position)
```

***Notice the change in comments at the bottom of each method***

As far as I can tell, both of these should accomplish the same exact thing, but they don't.  One works great until I get the recursion limit error.  The other doesn't really work at all, but I get no recursion error.

Why would these return different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second version you are using a `return` statement in the `for` loop.  Such a return interrupts the for loop, of course, which will never get resumed.

What you want instead is to have a call to `spread()` return a list of points, possibly empty.  Then in the caller you append these new answers to a list of to-be-processed points.  The caller would work by repeatedly popping an item off that list, calling `spread()`, and appending all new points it got into the list --- and repeating until the list is empty.

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks.  That's exactly what is wrong, and your solution makes perfect sense.